# Function with .onLoad & assign variable to otherPackage::variable. Devtools::check doesn't find variable when it runs examples

Tags: r, devtools, r-s4

This is very similar to what has been asked [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/handling-namespace-with-onload/18098)
I'm doinig in zzz.R :

```
.onLoad <- function(...) {

 assign("myVar",externalPackage::myVar, envir = .GlobalEnv)

 }
```

and set up also a file Package.R

```
NULL
globalVariables(c("myVar"))
```

I do that because I want to be able to modify the content of `externalPackage::myVar` and otherwise `externalPackage::myVar` is locked. Here I copy the content of `externalPackage::myVar` and I'm able to modify `myVar` now.

So now I'm happy. I can call  `myVar` in replacement of `externalPackage::myVar` everywhere in my different functions.

But it doesn't pass devtools::check() (R CMD check) when it tried to run examples.
It's because it try to call `myVar` without success.

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in ‘myPackage-Ex.R’ failed

  object 'myVar' not found
```

It doesn't find it. What should I add to make it works ?

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a new env and named it solve the issue when executing examples during R CMDcheck

```
 myEnv <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
 attach(myEnv, name="varEnv")
 assign("myVar", mypackage::var, envir = as.environment("varEnv"))
```